# Unexpected behavior of Gaussian filtering with Scipy

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

Given that I have an image `f(x,y)` loaded, for example,

[image]

I want to compute the Gaussian derivative `∂/∂x ∂/∂y G*f` of the image `f`, where `G` is a Gaussian filter and `*` denotes convolution. This is easily done using Scipy:

```py
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
imshow(gaussian_filter(g, sigma, order=1))
```

With `sigma=50` this produces the following result:

[image]

Now, for applicationary reasons, I need to do the computation with `mode='constant'`:

```py
imshow(gaussian_filter(g, sigma, order=1, mode='constant', cval=0))
```

Still, the result looks reasonable:

[image]

However, note that my image's background's intensity is `1` and not `0`. Hence, it should be reasonable to use `cval=1`:

```py
imshow(gaussian_filter(g, sigma, order=1, mode='constant', cval=1))
```

[image]

Now this is unexpected! This result makes no sense, does it?

For the record, I also checked the partial differentials `∂/∂x G*f` and `∂/∂y G*f`. Whereas

```py
imshow(gaussian_filter(g, sigma, order=[0, 1], mode='constant', cval=1)
```

looks reasonable

[image]

the other one

```py
imshow(gaussian_filter(g, sigma, order=[1, 0], mode='constant', cval=1)
```

does not:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Really looks like a bug. Try using general convolution operator and give it the Kernel you want. Do you have something like that in SciPy?

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in `gaussian_filter` that manifests itself when both `order` and `cval` are nonzero. [Specifically, it's here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L343):

```
for axis, sigma, order, mode in axes:
    gaussian_filter1d(input, sigma, axis, order, output, mode, cval, truncate)
    input = output
```

The filter performs repeated 1d convolution, and each time it passes in `cval` to 1d filter. Problem is, if there were any derivatives taken, then `cval` should be set to 0 because the derivative of any constant is zero. This is why the result is wrong with `order=[1, 0]` but not with `order=[0, 1]`. Without testing (don't have SciPy dev environment), I think the following would be correct:

```
for axis, sigma, order, mode in axes:
    gaussian_filter1d(input, sigma, axis, order, output, mode, cval, truncate)
    if order > 0: 
        cval = 0.0
    input = output
```

#### Workaround

A nonzero `cval` can be emulated by subtracting it from the image before filtering (and adding back after filtering only if the order is zero). Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

g = np.ones((500, 500))
g[200:300, 200:300] = 2
sigma = 50
cval = 1
gf = gaussian_filter(g-cval, sigma, order=1, mode='constant')
plt.matshow(gf)
plt.show()
```

returns

[image: filtered]

which is the expected result. (My original image is a bit different from yours, and I use a different visualization tool.)

Comment: Two remarks: 1) I think `if order > 0: cval = 0` should go before `gaussian_filter1d` in your first snippet. 2) The `gaussian_filter` in your scecond snippet computes derivatives of the image, and so the `+ cval` at the of the line adds to the *derivatives*, so I think it is wrong.

Comment: I agree with the second point, not with the first. The value of cval should change to zero _after_ a derivative is taken. On subsequent runs of the loop it's already zero.